# How to call a function for every for iteration of a zip of two lists?

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

I have two lists:
`a=[1,2,3]`, `b=[a,b,c]`

I want for each `zip` of those two to call a function, but not to do it in a trivial way inside a for loop. Is there a pythonic way? I tried with a `map`:

`map(func(i,v) for i,v in zip(a,b))`

but it does not work

Comment: *it does not work* How is that so? Please show the outcomes of what you've tried

Comment: and why those outcomes don't satisfy you (what is your expected output / behavior)

Comment: To use map, you would just specify `map(func, a, b)`. Or you can use what you've written above in a list comprehension. But if you don't want to collect the results of your function, a for loop will be just as fast and more explicit about your intentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** the function `func` doesn't return anything, you could use:

```
any(func(i, v) for i,v in zip(a, b))
```

Which will return `False` but not accumulate the results.

This would not be considered "Pythonic" by many since `any()` is being used for its side-effects, and therefore isn't very explicit.

Answer (score 5):

The pythonic way *is* the for loop:

```
for i, v in zip(a, b):
    func(i, v)
```

Clear, concise, readable.  What's not to like?

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension is almost always faster or equivalent to `map`.  If you append the results of the comprehension to a list (as in the example), then a comprehension is also faster than a `for loop`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = []

def foo(x, y):
    global c
    result = x * y
    c.append(result)
    return result


>>> c
[]

>>> [foo(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
['a', 'bb', 'ccc']

>>> c
['a', 'bb', 'ccc']
```

Comment: The function does not return anything, It does file manupulation

Comment: @curious I don't see no files here. And the function indeed does return a value.

Comment: My function I mean returns nothing. It does something with files.So why to use a list comprehension?

Comment: In that case, a `for loop` _is_ most pythonic.